# C++/WinRT Console: Initializing BackgroundDownloader crashes the program

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I recently started playing with C++/WinRT (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264).

My goal is to create an app that downloads a file and saves it to the downloads folder. I decided to use BackgroundDownloader class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader?view=winrt-19041).

However, when I try to create `BackgroundDownloader` instance my program crashes with the following exception:
`Exception thrown at 0x76729AB2 in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x004FEEF4.`

```
int main()
{
   // The line bellow causes the crash:
   winrt::Windows::Networking::BackgroundTransfer::BackgroundDownloader backgroundDownloader;
}
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader): *"An app that uses `Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer` to communicate through a toast notification must declare that it is Toast capable in the app manifest file."* - Are you following the contract?

Comment: C++/WinRT throws `winrt::hresult_error` errors that you can catch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/error-handling#catching-exceptions  I bet error.code().value is equal to 0x8007109A (ERROR_NOT_APPCONTAINER) because your environment is incorrect (you must use packaging).

Comment: @IInspectable, my application does not "communicate through a toast notification" and it does not even have an app manifest file (it's not UWP/packaged app).

Comment: If your are using a console project or other desktop projects, you may not use the [BackgroundDownloader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader?view=winrt-19041) API, because the **Attributes** of the API does not list the [DualApiPartitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.dualapipartitionattribute?view=winrt-19041) class which indicates that the type is supported in desktop apps.

Comment: @SimonMourier it is not necessary anymore. WinRT can be used with Win32 apps

Comment: @mishmashru - sure but not all WinRT APIs can be used.

Comment: @SimonMourier you're right. When I tried to catch the exception I got this message: "This operation is only valid in the context of an app container.". Unfortunately, packaging the application didn't help (package != container). I assume that the BackgroundDownloader can be used only by UWP apps, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is a very unclear moving area... Official rule is here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/uwp-apis-callable-from-a-classic-desktop-app *"if an API requires a package identity, a WPF, Windows Forms, or Win32 app cannot call it unless the app is packaged in an MSIX package."* and *"WPF, Windows Forms, or Win32 app is not allowed to call the API unless the app has been converted to a UWP app."* I don't see the clear relation between "package identity" and "UWP". I think "appcontainer" means "sandbox" and a Win32 app never has a sandbox anyway, package (identity) or not.

Answer (score -2):

WinRT is a bunch of COM interfaces so you need to initialize the subsystem first.
You must initialize the WinRT apartment first like this

```
winrt::init_apartment();
```

or

```
winrt::init_apartment(apartment_type::single_threaded);
```

for UI applications

Comment: Have you tried what you propose? it doesn't change anything. Read the comments carefully

Comment: I've just tested your solution. Sadly, neither of the mentioned options works.

Comment: I'm not using BackgroundDownloader but init_apartment() call is necessary to call WinRT APIs. And this is how I'm using WinRT